# vba add template page to end of current document

Tags: vba, ms-word, subroutine, word-template

How would the VBA code in my `Sub ButtonNext_Click()` appear if I wanted to append a Word 2016 template as a new page at the end of my current document and continue with my forms referencing that new page?
The stack overflow posts I've read suggest to me a combination of `documents.Add Template` and `range.Insertfile` are necessary but, I suspect, insufficient.

The VBA code in my current document produces only a single page which the client must save and/or print before populating a new page. Quite cumbersome. (I anticipate the template I would append need not contain the modules of the original document if I can continue to use the forms from the original document. Only the bookmarks and table).

Comment: Save the content that you need to repeat as a building block, then insert that at the end of the document. Ensure that the bookmarks you are using enclose some dummy text so that they get deleted when you insert the proper text.

Comment: I spent the last couple of hours looking at Building Blocks. A bit intimidating. I probably should rewrite the entire project. But hesitate.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev Thank you for the tags update